# ¿Cómo funciona el método myspinner.setSelection()?

Tags: android

No consigo seleccionar la posición en el spinner, según el método *setSelection*()
se le agrega el índice en el cual se tiene que posicionar al cargar o ¿es por el ciclo de vida de la actividad que debo cargarlo despues del *Oncreate*()?

```
consulta(id) {
//aca hago las consulta y asigno los valores 

    spgenper.setSelection(getItemPositionById(cursorListaSexo,cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CP_DB_Adapter.C_SEXO)), SexoDBAdapter.C_ID));
}
```

Este es el otro metodo en el cual le paso arriba

```
private int getItemPositionById(Cursor c, long id, String s){

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(s))== id){
            return c.getPosition();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: en OnCreate debes incluir código que tiene que ocurrir una sola vez

Comment: Podrías colocar tu fragmento de código? Me pasó una vez que lo que debía hacer era colocar el `spinner.setSelection(position);` después del    `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @MarkHernandez Cuando selecionas un elemento este realiza un cargado de la actividad? esa podría ser la razón

Comment: es que obtengo un ID desde otra actividad el la paso la recibo en el oncreate(), del oncreate(), mando a llamar un metodo consulta(ID) , el metodo me hace la labor de cargar todos lo valores de mi db a los edittext, los cuales no tengo problemas , el problema es cuando quiero cargar la posicion que guarde en la db al spinner

Answer (score 1):

Deberías mantener un ArrayList con tus items, para poder usar indexOf y obtener el valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
   ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(5);

   // añadir valores
   arr.add("H");
   arr.add("E");
   arr.add("X");
   arr.add("G");    

   System.out.println("E tiene indice " + arr.IndexOf("E")); // 1
```

Es decir

```
 myspinner.setSelection(arr.IndexOf("valor"));
```

Comment: si uso un cursor no abria porblemas con ese metodo??